# LaTeX help - multiple answers using set bracket / cases

Tags: article-writing

I'm brand new to LaTeX and am writing up a dissertation. I have read through several LaTeX guides but have not been able to find the answer there. Does anybody know how to use this `{` to show several possible answers? For example when defining the Kronecker delta:

[image: Kronecker]

I need to be able to split off several times within one equation. Please help!

**Edit** - is it impolite to ask that whoever rated my question down could explain why? I am fairly new to this forum and would like to be able to improve my questions based on the standards and etiquette here, but am not sure what is wrong with my question until someone tells me.

Comment: Is not it better that you ask these kind of questions in tex.stackexchange

Comment: @Vafa: You are absolutely right and I suggest this to the OP, too. However we could argue that the OP wants to know about MathJaX ;)

Comment: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5025/752) answer to the meta question [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/752).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\delta_{ij} =
    \begin{cases}
            1, &         \text{if } i=j,\\
            0, &         \text{if } i\neq j.
    \end{cases}
```

is what you are looking for.

Use `&` to split columns and use `\\` for new rows (=cases). Best way to learn what you want is via trial and error, it should be very easy to understand the exact syntax. Alternatively search for the `cases` environment.

**Edit:** Just as a personal preference, I suggest ending every column with a `,` - like I did with the cases - and the last line/case with a `.`.

**Edit 2:** You can look up the `cases` environment [here](http://timmurphy.org/2011/12/12/math-case-definitions-in-latex/).